# UI Router not evaluating routes in Wordpress Theme

Tags: angularjs, wordpress, angular-ui-router

I'm building a wordpress theme using AngularJS and have switched to using ui-router instead of ngRoute. Generally things work properly except when I refresh the page or type the URL into the browser. The page loads but no state is loaded. The only exception is on /blog which is the one page which doesn't match a wordpress URL. Wordpress throws a 404 but Angular loads the correct route - I don't understand how what wordpress does is affecting Angular because in all cases the same file (index.php) is loaded and Angular itself starts as evidenced by the console.log().

I had very similar configuration using ngRoute and everything worked correctly whether wordpress throws a 404 or not.

When clicking on menu links, the states load correctly and URLs change as specified.

If I uncomment the 'otherwise' statement is fires on all URLs except /blog and redirects to the home page.

In the error cases (all except /blog) the diagnostic state $on() events do not fire.

The top of the main angular JS code.

```
app = angular.module('app', ['ngSanitize','ngAnimate', 'ui.router']);

app.config(function($locationProvider) {
    $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
});

app.run( function($rootScope) {

  console.log('angular');

  $rootScope.$on('$stateChangeStart', 
    function(event, toState, toParams, fromState, fromParams){ 
      console.log('start');
    });

  $rootScope.$on('$stateNotFound', 
    function(event, toState, toParams, fromState, fromParams){ 
      console.log('not found');
    });

  $rootScope.$on('$stateChangeError', 
    function(event, toState, toParams, fromState, fromParams, error){ console.log(error); });

});    

app.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {

  // $urlRouterProvider.otherwise("/");

  $stateProvider
    .state('root', {
      url: "/",
      templateUrl: myLocalized.partials + 'front.html',
      controller: 'Main'
    })
    .state('portfolio', {
      url: "/portfolio",
      templateUrl: myLocalized.partials + 'portfolio.html',
      controller: 'Portfolio'
    })
    .state('portfolio.item', {
      url: "/portfolio/:slug",
      templateUrl: myLocalized.partials + 'portfolio-item.html',
      controller: 'Portfolio'
    })
    .state('blog', {
      url: "/blog",
      templateUrl: myLocalized.partials + 'blog.html',
      controller: 'Blog'
    })
    .state('page', {
      url: '/:slug',
      templateUrl: myLocalized.partials + 'content.html',
      controller: 'Page',
      resolve: {
        pageData: function(WPService, $stateParams) {
          console.log($stateParams);
          return WPService.getPageBySlug($stateParams.slug);
        }
      }
    });

});
```

I have `<base href="/" />` included in the head of the page and the ui-view attribute set in my index.php file.

Answer (score 0):

After digging into ui-router code I found out this was to do with trailing slashes. Wordpress .htaccess (I think) adds a trailing slash to the URL whenever it matches a page or other resource within wordpress. This was causing ui-router to not recognise the URL as none of my routes/states had a slash at the end. In the case of 404s wordpress didn't add the slash hence ui-router matching correctly and handling the route.

I resolved this by modifying wordpress permalink settings to not have a trailing slash.

Edit: you can also use $urlMatcherFactoryProvider.strictMode(false); in the config block to allow trailing slashes